# Get union records and duplicate count from two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables **A** and **B**.
Table **A** Column contains values from 1 to 9 . and Table **B** Contains values 2,6,7.
Now my requirement is to get **UNION** of **A** and **B** and count of duplicate records. I'm using SqlServer.

My result should be like this

ResultColumn Count

```
  1         1
  2         2
  3         1
  4         1
  5         1
  6         2
  7         2
  8         1
  9         1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Use `UNION ALL` to account duplicates.

```
SELECT
    [Column],
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM(
    SELECT [Column] FROM TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Column] FROM TableB
)t
GROUP BY [Column]
```